# Вытащить нужное из массива

Tags: php

```
var_dump ($response);
```

Возвращает такой набор данных:

```
    object(PayCheckout\ApiResponse)#12 (12) {
  ["apiResult":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["actionPerformed":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["traceReference":protected]=>
  string(18) "201610000444676622"
  ["paymentReference":protected]=>
  string(18) "201610062444645456"
  ["transactionReference":protected]=>
  string(18) "201610062444645456"
  ["errorCode":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["errors":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["warnings":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["errorToShowToConsumer":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["redirectInfo":protected]=>
  string(113) "https://sandbox.paycheckout.com/start?PayCheckoutReference=201610062444645456&ws=78AA8E68C158A66CCF7457459FBB0C4A"
  ["transactionResult":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["apiReturnValues":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

Как получить вот эту ссылку `https://sandbox.paycheckout.com/start?PayCheckoutReference=201610062444645456&ws=78AA8E68C158A66CCF7457459FBB0C4A`
из всего этого набора данных?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
 /**
  * @return string
  */
 public function getRedirectInfo()
 {
    return $this->redirectInfo;
 }
```

Это было вытащено из API, которым вы пользуетесь. Неужели сложно было сделать это самому?